# Power BI Date slicer not working as per data in the table

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a dashboard. I used date slicer to filter dates to reflect data on the table. There are data in table till 2022 but the data slicer is moved beyond 4/31/2021 is not showing data in the tables.
Could you please help me out/? I am stuck here. [The table with data till 2022[The table with data of April] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbZAU.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/C76H0.png) [table shows no data beyond April 2022] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlwF9.png)

Well, when I move the date slicer it should worked as intended as it is showing blank data after April 2022 in the table even though I see there is data.

[image: Screenshot_4]

[image: Screenshot_5]

[image: month data view added]

[image: Model view added]

[image: datatype date for date table]

[image: datatype to date for dispensed]

[image: realtionship between referrals vs date]

[image: many to many relationship]

Comment: Can you show the data fields for the Month column and slicer date in Power BI data view via screenshot?

Comment: @M.P. I have attached the screenshots as requested.

Comment: What I mean is a screenshot in the PBI data view.

Comment: There are Report view, Data view and Model view in the Power BI Desktop. Please attach screenshots for the Month column and LastDayOfMonth column on Data view and the relationship of Date and Ig_Ops Referrals_2020 tables on Model view.

Comment: @ M.P. I have added the month data view and model view of the tables as requested.

Comment: I want to see Month column of the lg_Ops Referrals_2020 table on Data view. Also, on which data fields is the relationship between both tables made based?

Comment: @M.P. I have added the month column data view of the Referrals table and also lastdayofMonth from date table is mapped to Month column of the referral table.

Answer (score 0):

- On Data view

Change the `Month` column of `Ig_Ops Referrals_2020` table from Date/Time to Date type.
Change the `LastDayOfMonth` column of `Date` table from Date/Time to Date type.

- On Model view

Make the relationship of `Month` column and `LastDayOfMonth` column to many-to-one.

Comment: @ M.P. I changed the date format for dispensed and date table required column to date data type but when trying to change the relationship of month column and lastdayofMonth column to many to one. It gives issue as shown in the last screenshot where it says, the cardinality you selected isn't valid for this relation.

Comment: I need to check the Date table. Try to make the relationship to many-to-many.

Comment: I made the relationships many to many but still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: How did you get the Date table? lastdayofMonth column of the Date table should contain unique values.

Comment: There was a dim date in database. So, I go it from there.